# I can't see "hello world"

Tags: android

I'm learning how to build an app through Android Studio. According to the tutorials, I'm supposed to see "Hello World" when I select Activity main/ Design. Instead, it's blank and when I add a button doesn't show anything in the design.

[image]

Did I miss anything? I checked different YouTube videos and forums, I couldn't find a response. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you update your question with layout.xml file?

Comment: can you show the xml part, as I am seeing a red exclamation on top right I think you need to refresh your layout. Just click on that icon and select force refresh

Comment: Thanks Guys, By using Vishal advice, I was able to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

As we both can see, in the upper right corner of your screen there is a red circle error indicator. Click on it and it will pop up a screen were the respective error is explained.

If there are any errors of syntax or stuff like that, it will provide short descriptions of where the error is located and how to solve it. If not, sometimes the program has some bugs and a ***"Refresh Layout"*** button will appear in the error log. Click on that and it might solve the problem.

You can also go in **File > Sync With File System** and **File > Sync Project With Gradle Files**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Gradle Scripts** and inside **Gradle Scripts** changes the dependencies for these:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Or just change the implementations:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

I think that it happens for the version of android.